# Can we increase a lowercase character by one

Tags: python

If I am having

```
char = 'a'
```

how can I increase the value into 'b' and then into 'c' and so on..

I don't want to replace it or change it. Its much like

```
char = char + 1
```

Comment: does `z` wrap around into `a`?

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> chr(ord('a') + 1)
'b'
```

Answer (score 8):

You can make an incrementer translation like this. I've mapped 'z' back onto 'a' in this case

```
>>> from string import maketrans, ascii_lowercase
>>> char_incrementer = maketrans(ascii_lowercase, ascii_lowercase[1:]+ascii_lowercase[0])
>>> 'a'.translate(char_incrementer)
'b'
```

you can just as easily apply it to a whole string

```
>>> 'hello'.translate(char_incrementer)
'ifmmp'
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
char = chr(ord(char) + 1)
```

or perhaps more pythonic like this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
char = ascii_lowercase[ascii_lowercase.index(char) + 1]
```

Beware that both of these methods have potentially undesired behaviour after you reach `z`.

Without knowing what you're going to use it for it's hard to say for certain, but I would look into whether you can do whatever it is you're doing in a way that avoids this problem. For instance, if you have code like this:

```
char = "a"
while True:
    if xxx():
        break
    if yyy():
        continue
    value = zzz()
    print char, value
    char = chr(ord(char) + 1)
```

Do it like this instead:

```
def find_values():
    while True:
        if xxx():
            break
        if yyy():
            continue
        yield zzz()

for char, value in zip(ascii_lowercase, find_values()):
    print char, value
```

Comment: I think the first one is better and second is unnecessary

Comment: The `.index` call is very slow

Comment: @gnibbler Its asymptotic behaviour as the string length increases is O(n), yes, but since the string is always 26 characters long it's not very slow. Timeit shows it's less than 50% slower than using `chr` and `ord`. But it's a good thing to be aware of when considering using the `index` method.

Comment: `ascii_lowercase[(ascii_lowercase.index(char) + 1)%26]` will make z -> a

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> chr((ord('a')+1)%97%26 + 97)
'b'
>>> chr((ord('z')+1)%97%26 + 97)
'a'
```